# What do we call the construction of a one object $n+1$-category (etc.) from multiobject $n$-category (etc.)?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

In general, when we have an $n$-something ($n$-category, etc.) and we decide to push everything up a notch, so $n$-cells become $n+1$-cells, and we end up with a $1$-object $n+1$-something, what do we call this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need more structure to do this, namely a monoidal structure. E.g. to push a set up to a one-object category that set needs to be a monoid. Then this procedure is called delooping.